# Animate form while it is submitted with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, animation, iframe

I don't know how to explain this, but I will do my best...
I am trying to submit a form normally, but the request result will be displayed  at a iframe. Everything goes fine to here. What I want to do (if it is possible) is to animate the form putting a message into it (like "sending...") ultil the iframe is load with the respose. I now this is so confuse, but take a look to my files:

### index.php

I have ommited the header because is so obvius.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php" target="my_iframe" id="form-upload">
    Choose your file here:
    <input name="uploaded_file" type="file"/>
    <input id="send-button" type="submit" value="Subir imagen"/>
</form>


<IFRAME name="my_iframe" SRC="upload.php" width="100%" height="200px" id="iframe1" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#send-button').sendImage({formid: "form-upload"});
    });
</script>
```

### upload.php

Just for testing porpuses.

```
<?php
if( isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) )
    echo "image sent";
```

### animate.js

This is where I am dealing with that. Because when I access the `index.php` always the message `sending...` is showed instance of the form elements.

```
var conf;

jQuery.fn.sendImage = function(args) {
    conf = $.extend( {
    }, args);


    this.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#'+conf.formid).submit();
        $('#'+conf.formid).html('sending...');
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a form is submitted, all processing on the current page stops. Anything you do must be BEFORE you actually submit the form. You alternative is to submit via AJAX.

Comment: Well, via ajax could not be an alternative because it is not able to sent/upload files. For this reason I made the trick with a html form element.

Comment: As I said, as long as you display your "sending..." panel BEFORE you submit then it can display *something*, but after submit all JS activity stops.